# Strange stack bash error: --: command not found

Tags: bash, haskell, haskell-stack

I have very simple haskell project with only executable `my-exec`. All it does is printing "Hello, world!" to console.

I want to create the script file `bin/setup.sh` which will run my executable and also do some `echo`

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack exec bash

echo Echo printing
my-exec
```

When I run it I get

```
$ ./bin/setup.sh
./bin/setup.sh: line 2: --: command not found
Echo printing
Hello, world!
```

And I don't understand what is the issue with this file and why it says `--: command not found` but still working as expected.

I understand that in this simple example I could write it in much easier form, but in my real situation I have to make like 10 of non trivial exec calls and don't want to duplicate `stack exec` multiple times.

So what can I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Remove the line `-- stack exec bash` or fix it to be a valid command.

Comment: @jordanm, it is not working without this line. And my question is exactly about how to fix it.

Comment: Well, it isn't working *with* the line either.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs it works _with_ the line. It just prints error. Just some garbage output. But overall it works and the desired behavior is almost achieved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the problem.  The first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
```

is interpreted by your operating system (e.g., the Linux kernel) as indicating that the script should be invoked using the equivalent of the shell command:

```
$ /usr/bin/env stack setup.sh
```

or, since `env` is just there to search the path for `stack`, the equivalent of:

```
$ stack setup.sh
```

If you run this manually, you'll get the same error.  That's because, when `stack` is invoked this way, it reads the indicated file, searching for a line of the form:

```
-- stack blah blah whatever blah blah
```

after the first `#!` line.  Normally, this line looks something like:

```
-- stack --resolver lts-10.0 script
```

which tells stack to run the script as if you had run the shell command:

```
$ stack --resolver lts-10.0 script hello.sh
```

which interprets `hello.sh` as a Haskell program, instead of a shell script, but runs it using the lts-10.0 resolver, and all is well.

However, you've told `stack` to use the command `stack exec bash`, so `stack` invokes your script with the equivalent of:

```
$ stack exec bash hello.sh
```

which is basically the same as running:

```
$ bash hello.sh
```

after setting up the `stack` paths and so on.

**FINALLY**, then, the shell `bash` is running your script.  Bash ignores the first line, because it starts with `#` character that indicates a shell comment.  But when Bash tries to interpret the second line, it's as if you entered the following command at the shell prompt:

```
$ -- stack exec bash
```

Bash looks for a program named `--` to run with arguments `stack exec bash`, and you get an error message.  The script keeps running, though, so the `echo` and `my-exec` lines get run as expected.

Wow.

Here's one way that may work for you.  You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec stack exec bash <<EOF

echo Echo printing
./hello

EOF
```

This shell script will invoke `stack exec bash` using a so-called "here doc", basically passing everything up to the `EOF` as a script file for `stack exec bash` to run.

Comment: "Wow." -- indeed! This was quite a rabbit chase down the hole.

Comment: Could we just `#!/usr/bin/env stack exec bash`? edit: Seems not. Everything after the command name in a `#!` line is given as a single first argument. Bummer.

Comment: Thanks! This is really detailed explanation!
Unfortunately, for my complicated real case that doesn't work, as I have `stack exec` calls inside `$(...)`. So I just made `bin/setup.sh` shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and call the script with `stack exec ./bin/setup.sh`.